# Dash Case Regex for CSS Selectors

Tags: regex

(I'm not very good at regular expressions)

I try to configure my SCSS linter so that it only accepts dash-cased class selectors:

```
a-b-c // VALID
a__b // INVALID (underscore)
& // VALID (used in SCSS)
&-q // VALID
&& // INVALID (not desirable)
a-1 // VALID
a-1- // INVALID (trailing dash is not desirable)
```

I have to deny camelCase / PascalCase:

```
Abc // INVALID
aBc // INVALID
```

I have to deny BEM (Block Element Modifier):

```
a__b--c // INVALID (double underscores and double dashes)
```

That's what I tried to do:

```
^&?[a-z]*([a-z0-9]*|\-?)*$
```

But it has some flaws:

```
q- // VALID (wrong: trailing dash)
q--w // VALID (wrong: double dashes)
```

Regex is really hard for me. I was trying to implement it by myself, but one thing always breaks another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^&?(?:-?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJzOUH/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `&?` - an optional `&` char
- `(?:-?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)?` - an optional group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of the following sequence of patterns:

  - `-?` - an optional hyphen
  - `[a-z0-9]+` - 1+ lowercase letters or digits
  - `(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of a `-` and then  1+ lowercase letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @Mandy8055 If you do not want to match an empty string, use `^(?!$)&?(?:-?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)?$`